# How to add Urdu Language to SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, .net, speechsynthesizer, urdu

I am working on a **queue management system** which is developed in *Dot Net*.  I need to enable this system to speak Token number in ***urdu***.
How I **add Urdu Language to SpeechSynthesizer**.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Speech Synthesizer does not support urdu and you cant add custom language to the speech synthesizer so you can use [cmusphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialdict)  CMU Sphinx as it is pretty open and scalable solution and I think it can be used at both client and server side and read its documents to add a custom languge and train it.

Comment: no it dont support urdu you have to add it manually by reading documents because you have to train it to understand urdu and its not easy

Comment: Ok, I will try. I just need to pronounce numbers in urdu.